# Display jQuery Datepicker calculated date elsewhere on page

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Currently I'm using jQuery ui Datepicker. I'm using the calendar to allow customers to choose delivery dates in one area of the page and it's set up with a minDate of 4 days, excluding weekends and holidays. I wondered if it's possible to display the final calculated minDate elsewhere on my page? I want to display the "Earliest possible Delivery Date" in the product description. Very, very new at jQuery and javascript.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Datepicker Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    //holidays
    var natDays = [
      [1, 1, 'New Year'], //2014
      [1, 20, 'Martin Luther King'], //2014
      [2, 17, 'Washingtons Birthday'], //2014       
      [5, 26, 'Memorial Day'], //2014
      [7, 4, 'Independence Day'], //2014
      [9, 1, 'Labour Day'], //2014
      [10, 14, 'Columbus Day'], //2013
      [11, 11, 'Veterans Day'], //2013
      [11, 28, 'Thanks Giving Day'], //2013 
      [12, 25, 'Christmas'] //2013     
];

    var dateMin = new Date();
    dateMin.setDate(dateMin.getDate() + (dateMin.getHours() >= 14 ? 1 : 0));
    AddBusinessDays(dateMin, 4);

     function AddBusinessDays(curdate, weekDaysToAdd) {
        while (weekDaysToAdd > 0) {
            curdate.setDate(curdate.getDate() + 1);
             //check if current day is business day
            if (noWeekendsOrHolidays(curdate)[0]) {
                weekDaysToAdd--;
            }
        }
    }    

    function noWeekendsOrHolidays(date) {
        var noWeekend = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
        if (noWeekend[0]) {
            return nationalDays(date);
        } else {
            return noWeekend;
        }
    }
    function nationalDays(date) {
        for (i = 0; i < natDays.length; i++) {
            if (date.getMonth() == natDays[i][0] - 1 && date.getDate() == natDays[i][1]) {
                return [false, natDays[i][2] + '_day'];
            }
        }
        return [true, ''];
    }
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
            inline: true,
            beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,           
            showOn: "both",            
            firstDay: 0,
                dateformat: "dd/mm/yy",
            changeFirstDay: false,
            showButtonPanel: true,       
            minDate: dateMin            
    });
  });
  </script>

<p>
<label for="datepicker">Desired Delivery Date: </label>
  <input class="input-medium" type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="ex. 01/01/2013" name="properties[Delivery Date]" readonly />
  <label><font size=1>Need it faster? Call us! (800) 880-0307</font>
  </label></p>
<style>
  #datepicker { height: 19px; }
  #datepicker {-webkit-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0; -moz-border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0; border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;}
</style>
```

Where I want to add datepicker date:

```
<p style="margin-top: 15px; margin-left: 40px; margin-top: -100px;"><font size=3>Please Choose From Delivery Options:</font></p>        
    <label for="Standard" style=" margin-left: 40px;">
      <input id="Standard" type="radio" name="properties[Delivery]" value="Standard Shipping" />
      <font>Standard Shipping</font><br>
      <font size=1 style="margin-left: 18px;">Earliest Date of Delivery: DATEPICKER DATE HERE </font>
    </label>
```

Comment: show the code that you tryed, we need this to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datepicker has several [options and methods](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/). One is the `onSelect` that has the `datestring` as an argument

You can add this in the datepicker options object. I there you can manipulate stuff and the inject the date in a separate element

**Place span tags where your date needs to be injected**

*You can take out the text in between*

```
<font size=1 style="margin-left: 18px;">Earliest Date of Delivery: <span id="delivery-date">DATEPICKER DATE HERE </span></font>
```

**jQuery:**

Please refer to the fiddle on the bottom. I had to turn of a feature to make it work. If the variable `noWeekendsOrHolidays` is correctly implemented in your code, you should have no problems.

```
// dateMin is the minimum delivery date
var dateMin = new Date();

// function setDeliverydate sets date elsewhere on the page
function setDeliveryDate(datestring) {
    var deliverdate = new Date(datestring);
    var day = deliverdate.getDate();
    var month = deliverdate.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = deliverdate.getFullYear();

    $("#delivery-date").text(month + "/" + day + "/" + year);

}

// set the initial delivery date
setDeliveryDate(dateMin);


// datepicker to choose a different delivery date
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    // beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidays,
    showOn: "both",
    firstDay: 0,
    dateformat: "dd/mm/yy",
    changeFirstDay: false,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    minDate: dateMin,

    onSelect: function (datestring) {
        setDeliveryDate(datestring);
    }

});
```

Here `#delivery-date` is the id of the span tag where you want to introduce the delivery date.

**updated:** http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/sZ5jq/21/

**with implementation:** http://jsfiddle.net/djwave28/sZ5jq/24/

Comment: Hi Daniel! Thanks so much for your help! I have tried this but, as I said in my comment above to zoranc, I am really new so having a hard time understanding. I did try your method but did not have any success. I have edited my post to include my code...maybe you can get a better picture of what I'm trying to accomplish. Thank you again!

Comment: I updated the source code for you to see where to implement it. Hope you get it to work ;)

Comment: Daniel, Thank you for sticking with me on this, I really appreciate it! I checked out your jsfiddle and think I understand why this wasn't working. I think I miscommunicated what I was after. I don't want the user to have to even touch the datepicker in order for the data to be displayed, I want it to already be there. It's to show the first earliest delivery date before they choose one. Maybe using the datepicker isn't the solution? I just thought I could use the calculations already there to populate elsewhere without having to click on the datepicker. Is this possible? Thanks again!!

Comment: @susan - I guess I misunderstood the question. I adjusted my answer for you. I used the minDate as the initial date for delivery. The datepicker is used if the user wants a different delivery date.
The function `setDeliveryDate()` is an isolated function. You can call it with any datestring to set the delivery date. You can delete the datepicker if you don't want it, your choice. Hope that helps.

Comment: Daniel, Once again thank you for your quick response and willingness to help! This is exactly what I was hoping for, however, wondering how to incorporate with my current code (above) in order to keep my minDate calculations intact (4 days excluding weekends & holidays and current day if after 2pm). Sorry if this is obvious, still learning. :)

Comment: I tested your script and it seems to work fine. The minDate value is adapted with keeping those off days in mind. look at the second jsfiddle for the complete integration in your script.

Comment: Awesome, awesome, awesome David!! I can't thank you enough, this is fabulous!!